# how to use iterated integral to find area of a region?

Tags: calculus, iterated-integrals

Use iterated integral to find area of a region bounded by $y=\sqrt{x}, y=3, x=0$, and $x=4$. sketch the region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the area of a rectangle, i.e it is $(3-\sqrt{3})(4-0)=4(3-\sqrt{3})$. Although not necessary in integral form we have $\int_{0}^4\int_{\sqrt{3}}^3dydx$. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rul8ankcel

Comment: I made a mistake, it is y=square root of x, thanks for the response

Comment: Then in this case we subtract the area under the graph $\sqrt{x}$ from the area of the rectangle. The area of the rectangle is $4*3$=12 and the area under the graph $\sqrt{x}$ is $\int_{0}^{4}\sqrt{x}dx$=$\int_{0}^{4}x^{\frac{1}{2}}dx$=$\frac{16}{3}$ and hence the final answer is $12-\frac{16}{3}$=$\frac{20}{3}$. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/61q7cng5je

Comment: what I did was 3= square root of x, then x=9; therefore, 3<=y<=9 and 0<=x<=4

Comment: No need since we want the area bounded by $\sqrt{x}\le y \le3$ and $0\le x \le 4$. The bounded area https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dpx7mw0i9d.